# Open a browser in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of 3 browsers, with the random choice I want to open a link randomly using one of the browsers in my list, but when I run the code, all browsers get opened.

```
my_url="URL"
dlist=[webdriver.Edge(),webdriver.Chrome(),webdriver.Firefox()]
web_driver = random.choice(dlist)
web_driver.get(url)
web_driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all of the entries in the list have parenthenses, an object will be created immediately, thus opening each browser.

Remove the parenthenses to have the *class* in the list, not an object.

```
dlist=[webdriver.Edge , webdriver.Chrome , webdriver.Firefox ]
                     ^                  ^                   ^ do not create an object
```

Then, create the object later after choosing the class

```
web_driver = random.choice(dlist)()
                                 ^^ create the object
```

Answer (score 3):

You're initalizing them all inside the list, just keep a list of the browsers then initialize them when selected

```
dlist=[webdriver.Edge,webdriver.Chrome,webdriver.Firefox]
web_driver = random.choice(dlist)()
```